# css has no effect in my Masterpage

Tags: asp.net

I have a Masterpage and I want to bind a part of this master page to a *.css file but no success.this is my Masterpage code:

```
<head runat="server" >
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" > 
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form runat=server>
<body>
   <table width=100% border=1>
    <tr width=100%>
      <td ></td>
      <div class=mainbody>
      <td width=80%  align=center>
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </td>
      </div>
      <td ></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </body>
</form>

</body>
```

and in my css file I have:

```
body
{

}
mainbody
{
  background-color:#a0ccff 
}
```

coild you please tell me,why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

class selectors should start with dot

```
.mainbody
{
  background-color:#a0ccff 
}
```

Comment: You also have incorrect markup. That div should live inside td -      
      <td width=80%  align=center><div class=mainbody>

Answer (score 1):

Look, you can't put a td inside a DIV element... Change your code from

```
... <head runat="server" >
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" > 
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form runat=server>
<body>
   <table width=100% border=1>
<tr width=100%>
  <td ></td>
  <div class=mainbody>
  <td width=80%  align=center>
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </td>
  </div>
  <td ></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </body>
</form>

</body>
 ...
```

to

```
<head runat="server" > <title></title>
        <link href="~/Styles/Test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" > 
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
           </head>
            <body>
        <form runat=server>

       <table width=100% border=1>
        <tr width=100%>
          <td ></td>
          <td width=80%  align=center>
          <div class=mainbody>
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </div>
      </td>
          <td ></td>
        </tr>
       </table>

     </form>      </body>
```

It will then work as you wish (I advice you to copy my code and Paste it in your SIte.Master file)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<link href="/Styles/Test.css" ...>
```

instead of :

```
<link href="~/Styles/Test.css" ...>
```

Comment: You probabably want <link href="Styles/Test.css" ...> assuming it is mean relatively

Comment: Yes, I mean maybe the problem occurs because web page doesn't "see" its css file.
If I remember well, the tilde symbol in URL works well only inside  asp: tags.